# Accessing Node.JS & npm bundled with IntelliJ 2019.2

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, npm, installation

[image]

The [*JavaScript & TypeScript*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2019-2-javascript--typescript) section of the “What’s New” page for [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2019.2 claims [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) is now bundled.

> Node.JS is now bundled with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate
>
> The Node.JS plugin now comes pre-installed with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

The [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/node-js.html) says I should find Node.js & npm in `Preferences` > `Languages and Frameworks` > `Node.js and NPM`.

But despite my owning a license for Ultimate, my installation of IntelliJ finds no [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) nor [*npm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)) to be installed. Notice the red text in this next screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of Preferences | Languages and Frameworks | Node.js and NPM for macOS]

➥ How can I locate or activate the supposedly-bundled Node.js and npm tools in my IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.2?

I filed [ticket IDEA-220901](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-220901?project=IDEA&clearDraft=true&description=%0A%0AIU-192.5728.98,%20JRE%2011.0.3%2012-b304.10x64%20JetBrains%20s.r.o,%20OS%20Mac%20OS%20X(x86_64)%20v10.14.6,%20screens%203360x1890;%20Retina).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not confuse  the [*Node.js plugin*](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6098-nodejs) with [*Node.js interpreter*](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). The plugin is now pre-installed with IDEA Ultimate edition, but the interpreter is not (and had never been planned to be bundled).

IDEA doesn't bundle Node.js with it, it has to be installed separately. As it's written in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/developing-node-js-applications.html, you have to download it from https://nodejs.org/en/#download. If you follow the standard installation procedure, in most cases IntelliJ IDEA detects Node.js itself. Otherwise, you have to spacify a path to installed interpreter manually in **Settings | Languages and Frameworks | Node.js and NPM.**

Comment: Did you read my quote of what's new in 2019.2? It says quite clearly, “now bundled” & “pre-installed”. That is the opposite of "download and install separately”.

Comment: I did:) Please don't confuse [Node.js plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6098-nodejs) with [Node.js interpreter](https://nodejs.org/en/): the former is pre-installed with IDEA, but the latter is not (and had never been planned to be bundled)

Answer (score 0):

go to 3 dots and then click on + sign then locate your node bin if you are using Linux then maybe its in **/usr/bin/node** then goto package manager and then do the same thing for npm it may be located at **/usr/lib/node_modules/npm**

Comment: I am asking about Node.js & npm being bundled *with* IntelliJ, not elsewhere in the OS.